# Django messages not working in admin model_save()

Tags: django, django-messages

I have the following save_model in MyModelAdmin, the print statement gives output in console, but on django admin, i can see default messages, but not my error message for some reason.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        try:
            transfer_money()
            super(MyModelAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
messages.set_level(request, messages.ERROR)
messages.error(request, 'YOUR MESSAGE')
```